# mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in while-loop

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, while-loop

I currently have this code but it gives me the error  `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given on line 22`

The code is this:

```
1   $servername = "localhost";
2   $user = "root";
3   $pass = "";
4   $db = "mafioso";
5
6   $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $pass, $db);
7
8   $cash_utbetaling[0] = 50000000;
9   $cash_utbetaling[1] = 40000000;
10  $cash_utbetaling[2] = 30000000;
11  $cash_utbetaling[3] = 20000000;
12  $cash_utbetaling[4] = 10000000;
13
14  $kuler_utbetaling[0] = 25;
15  $kuler_utbetaling[1] = 20;
16  $kuler_utbetaling[2] = 15;
17  $kuler_utbetaling[3] = 10;
18  $kuler_utbetaling[4] = 5;
19
20  $i = 0;
21  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM daily_exp ORDER BY exp DESC LIMIT 5");
22  while($row_best = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
23    
24    $acc_id = $row_best['acc_id'];
25
26    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE ID='".$acc_id."'";
27    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());
28    $row_top5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
29    
30    $result = "UPDATE accounts SET money = (money + ".$cash_utbetaling[$i]."), 
      bullets = (bullets + ".$kuler_utbetaling[$i].")  WHERE ID = ".$acc_id."";
31    mysqli_query($con, $result) or die("Bad query: $result");
32
33    $i++;
34  }
```

I can't seem to find the error, I am running the same code in another file and there is no issues.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207226/discussion-on-question-by-serverruby152-mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwritting `$result`

```
// This is supposed to be
//  a mysqli_result object ----------v-----v
while($row_best = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    // some code
    // $result is now a string. Next iteration will raises the warning
    $result = "UPDATE accounts SET ...";
}
```

So you need to give your variables distinct names. Naming a **query** `$result` is not the best choice.

---

Side note.

Your inner queries are vulnerable to SQL injections. One **should** use prepared statements instead of concatening strings.

In example :

```
// prepare the query
$query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE ID=?";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query)) {

    // bind the param
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $acc_id);

    // execute the query
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    // get the result. Of course, avoir using the same variable name, again :)
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
}
```

For more informations about prepared statements with mysqli, read the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or the [tutorials](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/examples) written by [@YourCommonSense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense)

Comment: Official documentation on mysqli. Yuck! I prefer to link to YCS' tutorials, which are the most correct and up to date documentation on MySQLi available online.

Comment: @Dharman I don't know them. If you think they are really better than the official docs, please edit my answer and provide the links

Comment: I will leave it here in the comments: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/examples

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem here is that you called the SQL query variable the same name as the result you used in the while loop. You overwrite it with a string on line 30:

```
30    $result = "UPDATE accounts SET money = (money + ".$cash_utbetaling[$i]."), 
      bullets = (bullets + ".$kuler_utbetaling[$i].")  WHERE ID = ".$acc_id."";
```

The easy answer is it was a typo, but you made many more mistakes.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mafioso");
$con->set_charset('utf8mb4');


$cash_utbetaling[0] = 50000000;
$cash_utbetaling[1] = 40000000;
$cash_utbetaling[2] = 30000000;
$cash_utbetaling[3] = 20000000;
$cash_utbetaling[4] = 10000000;
$kuler_utbetaling[0] = 25;
$kuler_utbetaling[1] = 20;
$kuler_utbetaling[2] = 15;
$kuler_utbetaling[3] = 10;
$kuler_utbetaling[4] = 5;
$i = 0;

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM daily_exp ORDER BY exp DESC LIMIT 5");
$daily_exp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// prepare update
$stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE accounts SET money = (money + ? ), bullets = (bullets + ? ) WHERE ID=?');

foreach ($daily_exp as $row_best) {
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $cash_utbetaling[$i], $kuler_utbetaling[$i], $row_best['acc_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $i++;
}
```

1. You need to enable error reporting instead of using `or die (mysqli_error())`, which would never work, because of missing argument.
2. Don't use while loop to go through the results. It is much better to fetch all the records at once or loop on the result using `foreach`. If you used my suggestion, then most likely you would avoid your typo at all.
3. You must use prepared statements. In your code the values are integers and constant, but I assume you would use variable input at some point, which means you need to use placeholders and parameters.
4. The SELECT query inside the loop wasn't doing anything, so I removed it from my answer.
5. You should strive to avoid N+1 queries problem. Try doing the same in one query only if possible.